# How do I disable kernel logging into the systemd journal?

Tags: linux, kernel, systemd

I'm using a device that spams kernel messages excessively (10-100 messages a second, Mediatek drivers...), where it is infeasible to remove the logging from the kernel itself (spread across hundreds of files).

I've accepted that dmesg is all but useless on this device, but unfortunately the systemd journal is also affected.

Is it possible to filter/disable logging kernel messages into the systemd journal?

Comment: Instead of disabling the logging of kernel messages, I would investigate the reason why mediatek drivers produce such a high level of output and what can be done about it. Kernel messages are quite useful.

Comment: I completely agree, but the output from these Mediatek drivers is just ridiculous. It spams several lines (of all available priorities) for things like turning on/off a CPU core or the battery voltage changing by a minuscule amount.

There is no way to stop the spam that I can see, each driver uses its own hard-coded logging configuration, best I can do is comment out the worst culprits

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Good Linux/Sysadmin practice would recommend you go with something like fzbd's solution in which you're silencing the specific log you don't need to see rather than disabling kernel messages wholesale.

Nevertheless, it's still worth mentioning that as of [systemd 235](https://lists.freedesktop.org/archives/systemd-devel/2017-October/039589.html), there's an option for disabling kernel messages within `journald.conf` file. The main journal.conf docs [mention this option](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/journald.conf.html) which allows you to disable journald from reading `/dev/kmsg`.

Version 235 may not be found in many distributions just yet, so you can check your systemd version with:

```
systemctl --version
```

If you have version 235 or above you can proceed by first making a backup of the original /etc/systemd/journald.conf file and then uncommenting the relevant line and changing it from `yes` to `no`:

```
ReadKMsg=no
```

Save, exit, and restart your journald service:

```
sudo systemctl restart systemd-journald.service
```

Comment: Many thanks, installed systemd from stretch-backports and ReadKMsg=no did the trick!

Comment: Instead of edit /etc/systemd/journald.conf it is better to override it with /etc/systemd/journald.conf.d/kfilter.conf (for example).

Comment: @Oleg Yeah, making things more modular is usually a good practice when possible, so yes that’d also a great option.

Answer (score 5):

See if your device's kernel module has some logging/debug parameter which you can disable:

```
modprobe $module_name
ls /sys/module/$module_name/parameters
```

If not, for systemd with version < 235, the best you can do is filter messages by log level, for example:

```
journalctl --priority=3
```

You can check the log values with `man syslog`.

Note that lowering the kernel logging levels using `kernel.printk` only affects console logging, so userland applications will still show the same messages, regardless of the values in this parameter.

Comment: As far as I know kernel.printk only affects kernel logging to TTYs? Sadly there are no exposed parameters for the drivers responsible for the spam

Comment: You are right, calls to printk() still show up on journalctl. I've revised my answer.